# Webpack - Copy images files

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs, webpack-file-loader

I'm currently using Webpack to pack our Angular2 application and i'm facing a problem.

I've read several documentations but I can't achieve how to copy some files in my output directory using the file loader.

Here is my current file hierarchy :

```
config
  | - webpack.common.js   
app        
  |- static
      | - css
           | - ...
      | - fonts
           | - ...
      | - img
           | - someimage.png
           | - anotherimage.png
  |- main.ts
```

and the (full) webpack.common.js :

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require("webpack")
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {    
    entry: { 
      app: './app/main.ts',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        path:'./built',
        chunkFilename: 'bundles/[id].chunk.js'
    },


    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'ts',
            exclude:'./out/'
        },
        {           
             test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
             include: [
                 path.resolve(__dirname, '/app/static/img/'),
              ],
             loader: 'file?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=./src',

        }
        ]
    },

     resolve: {
         extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.gif']
    },


     plugins: [
         new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
             template: './index.html'
         })
    ]
}
```

To execute webpack I play the command :

```
webpack --config Config/webpack.common.js  --bail
```

The ts file are correctly transpilled into javascript and copied into the  output directory, the index.html file is also present but there is none of my image files.

I think there is something wrong in my configuration file but I can't see what. I'm banging my head on it fore many hours so any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use url-loader to load images. Sample code is given below.

```
{
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: 'url?limit=10000!img?progressive=true' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Are you referring the gif files or corresponding css/sass files inside your entry js file.

```
   entry: { 
      app: './app/main.ts',
    }
```

Webpack will load all the files which have a reference in the entry point. If all your files are not in one entry point. Then you can add multiple entry points as shown below.

```
   entry: { 
      app: './app/main.ts',
      image: './app/something.ts'
    }
```

Also, i would put webpack.config.js file directly in the root directory to have better access to the whole ecosystem. Try moving it from config folder to root folder.

Comment: I tried with url-loader but I have exactly the same result. It behaves as if the gif files are not found (I have no mention of this file in the logs - even in verbose mode). Maybe something is wrong in the path and / or context definition.

Comment: So that means it works for other image types. are you having problem with only gif files?

Comment: No it doesn't works for any type of my "static" files (not only gif). For exemple, woff files are not copied

Comment: Can you paste the code which uses those static files. You need to consume them somewhere in your code for them to be transpiled.

Comment: by the way i have updated the answer with some other options. Hope you tried them as well.

Comment: It works ; following your suggestion I add an entry containing an single image and the file was successfully copied (with the file-loader and url-loader)   
 
     `entry: {
         appli: './app/main.ts',
          images : './app/static/img/background.png'
`    } . Thanks

Comment: Nice.  You don't have to create another entry point just for images. I am sure you must be using these images in less/sass/css files. Then you need to add that particular file to your entry point which is /app/main.ts  then those images will be automatically transpiled.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it was just a study case (not the best one I admit...)

Answer (score 1):

Creating separate entry point for images may not be what you want, depending on how you build CSS part of the project.  As alternative you can copy static files with [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) or grunt / gulp task.